# Overloading comparison operators

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble overloading the comparison operators `>` and `<`. I've tried two different ways but I'm still having trouble.

```
bool Car::operator ==(const Car &car)
{
    return mLNumber == car.GetNum();
}

bool Car::operator <(const Car &carB)
{
    return mLNumber < carB.GetNum(); 
}
bool Car::operator >(const Car &carB)
{
    return mLNumber > carB.GetNum(); 
}
int Car::GetNum()
{
    return mLNumber;
}
```

My `==` operator works just fine. I get the error that these operators don't exist. Here is my 2nd attempt.

```
bool Car::operator <(const Car &carA, const Car &carB)
{
    return carA.GetNum() < carB.GetNum(); 
}
bool Car::operator >(const Car &carB)
{
    return carA.GetNum() > carB.GetNum(); 
}
```

And I get the error that there are too many parameters. I also get this:

```
'Car::GetNum' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Car' to 'Car &'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try making your operators `const`:

```
bool Car::operator <(const Car &carB) const {
    return mLNumber < carB.GetNum(); 
}
bool Car::operator >(const Car &carB) const {
    return mLNumber > carB.GetNum(); 
}
```

**Edit:** And in this case, you should make the `GetNum()` function as `const` too because you are calling it on `const Car&` objects.

You don't need `GetNum()` either, you could just write

```
bool Car::operator <(const Car &carB) const {
    return mLNumber < carB.mLNumber; 
}
```

Comment: No, that's not the problem here. The problem is that `GetNum()` isn't `const`. The operators themselves aren't actually getting called on any `const` object.

Comment: @NikosChantziaras you should revise your downvoting policy - this is merely incomplete, not wrong. As is yours (the operators **should be const**, + you're not treating the other question - the error on multiple parameters). +1 from me because you were first (but still incomplete)

Comment: This doesn't solve the OPs problem at all, which is why I thought this is a bad answer. It's actually surprising that everyone else also didn't detect the real reason for the error. Of course the operators should be `const`, but it's not the actual problem here :-)

Comment: @NikosChantziaras sometimes, the slightest suggestion can be useful. Did it occur to you that making the operators `const` will give a compiler error `cannot call non-const method GetNum`? And make it clear that `GetNum` must be made `const`. Also, the second part actually does answer the question, since it removes `GetNum` altogether.

Comment: @NikosChantziaras life's unfair like that. </sarcasm>

Comment: @LuchianGrigore The best help should deal with the intermediate problem, so that he OP understands it step-by-step. The compiler error wasn't because of non-const operators.

Comment: @NikosChantziaras, the *first* answer got accepted ;)
My answer isn't wrong, I edited it (thanks). It **is** incomplete because I forgot to talk about operators defined outside classes (Luchian did in his answer).

Comment: @NikosChantziaras suit yourself. Pro-tip: stop whining. If this hadn't solved the problem, it wouldn't have got accepted. The op obviously found it useful.

Answer (score 3):

There's two problems in the code - **first**, logically, your operators are **immutable** on the type - they don't change the objects, they only analyze them, and you should be able to call them on immutable (`const`) objects. So, as alestanis pointed out, **make them `const`** (all operators and the getter method).

**Second**, `<` `==` and `>` are binary operators. There's two options to implement them: as free operators, or as members. You went with members, which is okay, but:

```
bool Car::operator <(const Car &carA, const Car &carB)
```

doesn't declare a binary operator. When you implement an operator as a member, the first parameter is implicitly the current object (`*this`), so it should be

```
bool Car::operator <(const Car &carB) const
```

The free operator would look like:

```
bool operator < (const Car& carA, const Car& carB);
```

Note that `const` on this one doesn't make sense since it's not a member. However, note that the first parameter (`carA`) is marked as const, which corresponds to the `const` applied to the method in the member version (which, under the hood, marks `this` as `const`).

Comment: That's not the problem here, since the operators in this particular case aren't called on `const` objects. The real problem is that `GetNum()` isn't `const`, so it can't be called on the `carB` object, which is `const`.

Comment: @NikosChantziaras did you read the whole answer? What about the "make them const (all operators and the getter method)" part? Being short-sighted and treating only the immediate errors are the trait of a beginner. So excuse me for going the extra mile!

Comment: This is a great answer, IMO, I was happy to here an extra mile long answer. How is this answer only +2 and so old?

Answer (score 1):

It would help to see where you're calling these operators.

Your second version with two Car arguments should be global operators. So drop the Car:: from the definitions if you use them. Move the declarations out of the Car class' body, too.

Since your calling GetNum on a const Car object, the Car::GetNum function also needs to be const. The dirtier way to do this is to cast away the const-ness, but that is frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is when you want to compare one `const` object and you operators is not marked as`const`, as a general rule, you should always mark functions and operators that do not change your object as `const` and this make life much easier. For example:

```
bool Car::operator ==(const Car &car) const // <-- This function is const
{
    return mLNumber == car.GetNum();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first case:

Your operators do not change data of operands, then it should be made const:

```
bool Car::operator <(const Car &carB) const {
                                    //^^^^^
    return mLNumber < carB.GetNum(); 
}
bool Car::operator >(const Car &carB) const {
                                   // ^^^^^
    return mLNumber > carB.GetNum(); 
}

int Car::GetNum() const
                //^^^^^
{
    return mLNumber;
}
```

In the second case, when operators accept 2 arguments, they should be implemented as free functions:

```
bool operator <(const Car &carA, const Car &carB)
{
    return carA.GetNum() < carB.GetNum(); 
}
bool operator >(const Car &carA, const Car &carB)
{
    return carA.GetNum() > carB.GetNum(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `car::GetNum()` isn't declared `const`, so you can't call it on `const` instances of `car`. The operators take a `const Car &carB` as argument, so you can't call `GetNum()` on `carB`, since `carB` is a `const` object, but `GetNum()` has not been declared `const`.

You should get into the habit of declaring all functions that don't modify the object as `const`. To declare a function as `const`, simply append `const` after the closing parenthesis. Both in the declaration, as well as the definition. For example:

```
class car {
    // ...
    void car::foo() const;
    // ...
};

void car::foo() const
{ /* ... */ }
```

Or, if you're defining it inline inside the class declaration:

```
class car {
    // ...
    void car::foo() const
    { /* ... */ }
    // ...
};
```

Although not strictly necessary in this particular case (meaning this isn't why the code doesn't compile), the operators themselves should also be declared `const` for the same reason (so that you can use them also on `const` objects.)